# Avro4S: Error when Deserializing Abstract Data Types (Could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type FromRecord)

Tags: scala, avro4s

I am using avro4s

https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s

I wrote this code

```
  import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
  import com.sksamuel.avro4s._

  sealed trait Dibble
  case class Dobble(str: String) extends Dibble
  case class Dabble(dbl: Double) extends Dibble

  case class Drapper(dibble: Dibble)

  val drapperIn = Drapper(Dabble(2.0))
  val bios = new ByteArrayOutputStream
  val avro = AvroOutputStream.binary[Drapper](bios)
  avro.write(drapperIn)
  avro.close()

  val is = AvroInputStream.binary[Drapper](bios.toByteArray)
  val drapperOut = is.iterator().toList.head
  is.close()

  println(drapperIn == drapperOut)
```

But I get the following error when reading binary data

> Error:(18, 47) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of
>   type com.sksamuel.avro4s.FromRecord[A$A449.this.Drapper] lazy val is =
>   AvroInputStream.binaryDrapper
>                                                ^ Error:(18, 47) not enough arguments for method binary: (implicit evidence$13:
>   com.sksamuel.avro4s.SchemaFor[A$A449.this.Drapper], implicit
>   evidence$14:
>   com.sksamuel.avro4s.FromRecord[A$A449.this.Drapper])com.sksamuel.avro4s.AvroBinaryInputStream[A$A449.this.Drapper].
>   Unspecified value parameter evidence$14. lazy val is =
>   AvroInputStream.binaryDrapper
>                                                ^

Comment: Which Scala version are you using?

Comment: scala version: 2.11.8

Comment: avro4s version 1.6.4

Comment: I compiled your code and it works. Are you sure this is all you're doing?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in copy pasting I guess. Dapper class should contain base trait and not the derived class. I have fixed the code now. It gives now the same error as mentioned in my question

Comment: Seems like sealed traits are not well supported (https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/issues/62). The suggestion is to use some other abstraction to model the data. I hope this get supported soon as sealed traits are very common way to model abstraction.

Comment: That's weird. I actually managed to compile the code properly.

Comment: I have added this test project https://github.com/mafayaz/avro4adt . You can check it out. Its compilation fails and give the same above error

Comment: seems like this issue "fails with sealed abstract class #10" was fixed in milestone 1.2.2, but this does not work in 1.6.4. And there is also no open issue at the moment to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I just pulled your project and it doesn't compile. Not sure how it previously worked.

Comment: The next release coming soon supports sealed traits better.